# how to use the macdeployqt -codesign option with Qt 5.4.1

Tags: macos, qt, code-signing, qt5.4, macdeployqt

According to [this Qt blog post](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2014/10/29/an-update-on-os-x-code-signing/):

> The -deep option signs the app bundle recursively, including contained
>   frameworks. While convenient to use, –deep is documented for
>   “emergency repairs and temporary adjustments only“. As of Qt 5.4
>   macdeployqt has a -codesign option that recursively signs the app
>   bundle without using –deep.

But on the Qt documentation page [Qt for OS X - Deployment](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/osx-deployment.html), the list of supported options for `macdeployqt` (at the bottom of the page) does not include `-codesign`.

So, does `macdeployqt` have a `-codesign` option for Qt 5.4.1?  If so, how do I use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the blog post references this code: -

```
macdeployqt foo.app -codesign=MyCertificate
```

It does appear that it does support the -codesign option for Qt5.4 and looks like they've not updated the docs accordingly.

To see the options for the tool, type the following in a Terminal window: -

```
macdeployqt --help
```

You shoud see that one of the options listed is

> -codesign=  : Run codesing with the given identity on all executables

Assuming you have an appropriate certificate in your keychain and are using Qt 5.4.x, then you should be able to codesign with the -codesign option

```
macdeployqt foo.app -codesign=MyCertificate
```

Where MyCertificate is the name of the signing certificate in your keychain